# AddPrinter.app hangs on Yosemite

Tags: network, macos, printing

I want to add a network printer on my MBP13R mid-2013. I open the dialog box `Add printer` (`Addprinter.app`). I begin to fill the form for IP adress of my printer (by typing the hostname). I only type a few letters and the window hangs.

The only way to stop it is to use `kill -9 PID` command in Terminal (using `ps aux|grep -i print` for obtaining the `PID` of `AddPrinter.app`).

After this I obtain the following lines in `Console`:

```
02/02/2015 16:32:57,316 com.apple.preference.printfax.remoteservice[3869]: __agent_connection_block_invoke_2: Connection error - Connection interrupted
02/02/2015 21:03:04,973 com.apple.preference.printfax.remoteservice[15832]: remote view marshal proxy failed to forward event to remote due to Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "Impossible de communiquer avec un utilitaire." (connection from pid 15827) UserInfo=0x600000477fc0 {NSDebugDescription=connection from pid 15827}
timestamp: 21:03:04.972 Monday 02 February 2015
process/thread/queue: com.apple.preference.printfax.remoteservice (15832) / 0x10e495000 / com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.15827
code: line 1217 of /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-103/NSViewServiceMarshal.m in __59-[NSViewServiceMarshal remoteViewMarshal:withErrorHandler:]_block_invoke
#communications_failure

02/02/2015 21:03:05,026 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.preference.printfax.remoteservice[15832]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
```

Do you have any idea for solving this trouble?

**Details:**

- Network: wire connection (thunderbolt adapter) with DHCP
- Yosemite 10.10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** the firewall app `HandsOff` blocked DNS requests even if I desactivated it. I uninstalled it and now it works fine.